# All possible Jordan Canonical forms of a nilpotent $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

Find all possible Jordan Canonical forms of a nilpotent $3\times 3$ matrix. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note (or show) that a matrix is nilpotent if and only if its only eigenvalue is $0$.  If you're proving this, it helps to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: So it would be all possible JCFs with eigenvalue $0$? Would the zero matrix be one of them?

Comment: Yes.  And I think so, but you should double-check the definition of nilpotent to see if they include $0$.  The usual definition, as far as I know, does include zero.